# Creating a printer device context succeeds except when running application under windbg

Tags: printing, windbg

This one's got me stumped. I've got a very simple little c program, as follows:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "windows.h"

int main()
{
    char cPrinter[200];
    DWORD count = 200;
    HDC hDC = NULL;
    GetDefaultPrinterA((LPSTR) &cPrinter, &count);
    printf("Hello world, my printer is %s\n", cPrinter);
    printf("Now I'm going to create a DC...\n");
    hDC = CreateDCA(NULL, cPrinter, NULL, NULL);
    printf("CreateDC returned the value %08x for my DC\n", hDC);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in a console window on a Windows 7 machine, I get the device context handle just as I would expect, but when I invoke it under windbg, I get a 06ba exception, and the CreateDC function returns a NULL. On the Windows 7 machine I've got a number of printers defined as indicated in the screenshot below:

[image: the printers I've got defined]

The two physical printers in the list are both networked but are online and available.

Changing the driver parameter to the CreateDC call to "WINSPOOL", doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It turned out to be a network printer port that was referencing a workstation ip address that had been changed so the ip address was now invalid. While this port was not selected for the default printer it seems it was still somehow being queried. Anyhow, deleting the port solved the problem.